# Rails: Questiona bout polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 4 models I'm working with: Base, Stat, Feature and Element.

A Base has many Stats, has many Features OR has many Elements, but only ever one of the three (a Base won't have many Stats AND have many Features, for example).

What would the associations between these models look like? Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible? If at all possible, I'd like avoid something like:

```
Base
has_many :stats
has_many :features
has_many :elements
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the way I see it:

- Base has many states
- FeaturedBase inherits from Base AND has many features
- ElementBase inherits from Base AND has many elements

But that's not really a Rails question, but an OODesign one.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input. Right now, I'm going with Stats, Features and Elements each belonging to a Base, and Base doesn't have any sort of association. This actually works, since I'll only be going down the chain, and not up it.